# popup on page load with cookie not working

Tags: jquery

I am using [this](http://papermashup.com/demos/jquery-subscription-box/#) as example to create my pop up on page load. The code is working fine while on local but when I added it on the server its not working. I think some script might be conflicting with it but I am not sure which. I am running on Magento 1.7.

1) here is the [link](http://www.miirue.com/m1) i'm working with.

2) http://jsfiddle.net/5USUu/

#### Step 1

Add CSS & JS

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getJSUrl('pop/colorbox.css'); ?>" media="screen"/>
<link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" target="_blank" href="<?php echo $this->getJSUrl('pop/popup.css'); ?>" />
<script language="javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getJSUrl('pop/colorbox.js'); ?>"></script>
```

#### Step 2

Add function before `</head>`

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function (){ 
   // load the overlay
    if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) {
        var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*15;
        var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
        document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
        $.colorbox({width:"580px", inline:true, href:"#subscribe_popup"});
    }

    $(".open_popup").colorbox({width:"580px", inline:true, href:"#subscribe_popup"});
```

});

#### Step 3

add HTML at the footer

```
<p>The subscription popup will activate if no cookie is set. Once the popup is closed a cookie is set which expires every 15 days. You can manually activate the subscription box below.</p>

<a href="#" class="open_popup">Click here to open the popup</a>

<!-- This contains the hidden content for inline calls for the subscribe box -->
<div style='display:none'>
<div id='subscribe_popup' style='padding:10px;'>
<h2 class="box-title">Never miss an update from Papermashup</h2>
<h3 class="box-tagline">Get notified about the latest tutorials and downloads.</h3>
<!-- BEGIN #subs-container -->
<div id="subs-container" class="clearfix">
  <!-- BEGIN .box-side -->

  <!-- BEGIN #subs-container -->
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- END subscribe popup-->
```

Comment: You're using jQuery, but I don't see it imported, are you sure jQuery is available?

Comment: $(document).ready(function (){...}); //document, not "document" wraped in quotes

Comment: @cfs Please look at the link I'm working with, its imported.

Comment: @roasted Changed to be document instead but still not working..

Comment: @rzrz Looking at your fiddle, you haven't imported jquery or the colorbox extension.

Comment: @cfs on fiddle & on my local popup onpageload's working fine but it aint that so on my server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/5USUu/6/

You have to include jQuery and then the `[colorBox.js][1]` plugin you are using, once included everything should work. I see a pop up with the text `Never miss an update from Papermashup` in colorBox.

I also changed:

```
$("document") => $(document)
```

View the [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/5USUu/6/)

The fact it works locally and not on your server, means the file is probably not on your server (or transferred with a wrong mime type), check your `Console` for errors to debug.

Also, I see looking at your source code (http://miirue.com/m1/) that you are include the jquery library twice, also I see your including loads of other libraries, so you would probably need to use [jQuerys noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) method.

I see so many issues with your code, im not suprised its not working. Debug using your console, make sure html is all valid, and all resources and transferred with the correct mime type and actually exist.

Nothing seems to be wrong with your code (apart from $("document") => $(document) ), if your javascript breaks somewhere, it will break everything, so make sure your syntax is valid and correct.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, it is indeed working on my local & fiddle. I can't figure it out why it won't work on my server do check the link (1) on my question. Thanks :)

Comment: hi can u elaborate more about what's console? (I have hosted them correctly on my server.)

Comment: In chrome, right click > inspect element > console (this will list all the errors in your code, which there are loads!! fix these, then it will work)

Comment: I've cleaned up but do u have any idea what _Uncaught TypeError_ ? 

its showing in console right after 
`$(document).ready(function (){  `
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready' 

Thats the last error left, and i've added `<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
</script>`

Comment: on line 141 of your source, You are referencing jQuery with a `$`, change that last doc ready to `jQuery.(document).ready...`, Where you see the error in your console, You can click on the text on the far right `http://miirue.com/:141` to show your where the error is.

Comment: okay have changed all $ to jQuery. Now I have `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (:14`  what could be the issue?

Comment: it should be `jQuery(document).ready..` not `jQuery.(document).ready..` (remove the `.` after `jQuery`)